# Spawner With error message :member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a infinite runner and in the spawn script it always this error message and cant figure out how to fix it : Assets/Scripts/Spawn.cs(16,14): error CS0542: `Spawn.Spawn()': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] obj;
    public float spawnMin = 1f;
    public float spawnMax = 2f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        // Spawn();
    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Invoke("Spawn", Random.Range(spawnMin, spawnMax));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your `class` is the-same as a another function(`Spawn`) inside the `class`. Simply rename your `Spawn`() function to something else and your problem should be solved. Maybe, make the `S` in your spawn function name to be lowercase while the one in your script name capitalized?

```
void spawn () {
...
}
```